# How to reset a view in a viewflipper with button click

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am dealing the view flipper  with three views.  The only problem which I couldn't able to solve is,
In main.xml I have  one button(xyz) and when I click that button(xyz) the first view of the view flipper will appear after moving to the  third view I closed the view flipper.

But when I  click the button (xyz) once again to reopen the view flipper  the third view is appearing(from where I closed the view flipper) instead of first view. Remember the button (xyz)  doesn't belongs to viewflipper

how to solve this, any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove your view by using Viewflipper.removeView(id)./*id=1,2,3 in ur case.*/